# Generate 500 API requests per second using ScheduledExecutorService class in Java

Tags: java, performance, rest

I am trying to write some test client for one of my REST API. I am using the ScheduledExecutorService class in java to schedule an api call per 2 millisecond so that it reaches my target rate of 500 calls per second. My code looks like this.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
    scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //REST API CALL METHOD
        }
    }, 1, 2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I am looking at the metrics and the requests per second doesn't even cross 100 requests per second. How should I modify the service to produce more calls per second.

Comment: Have you considered using a tool like [Gatling](http://gatling.io/#/) or [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) to test your service rather than writing your own harness? Alternatively, have you checked out if something in your Rest API is taking 1s to respond?

Comment: I considered using JMeter and that works fine for me. But I need to vary the input data in a specific pattern that can be achieved programatically only. I tried using JMeter GUI.

Comment: Well, then you've got two possible sources of problems. Can you be sure that each thread completes in 200ms to service that rate? And then are you sure that your service is capable of servicing that number of concurrent requests with a response time of 200ms or less?

Comment: Requests not ending was the issue. I was receiving the reply in less than 200 ms but the client was not ending the connection right away and hence the thread took longer than 200ms to end. I got it fixed.